# XSLT splitting an element into new elements based on multiple delimiters

Tags: xslt

I found some code here which is a nice start but it's a little different than what I'm looking for and I'm not sure how to proceed.  What I want to do is copy the entire XML file, create new elements by splitting the Author element based on multiple delimiters and also get rid of the original "Author" element name.  Each Author "set" is delimited by a semicolon and ends with a carriage return or just a carriage return as in Record 4.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm an XSLT novice and any explanation for a provided solution would be great as I want to understand the solution not just make it work.  Thanks.

The code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:e="http://localhost">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<e:e>AuthorName</e:e>
<e:e>AuthorLocation</e:e>
<e:e>AuthorPhone</e:e>
<xsl:variable name="vElement" select="document('')/*/e:*"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Author/text()" name="tokenizer">
    <xsl:param name="pString" select="string()"/>
    <xsl:param name="pPosition" select="1"/>
    <xsl:if test="$pString">
        <xsl:element name="{$vElement[$pPosition]}">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(concat($pString,';'),';'))"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenizer">
            <xsl:with-param name="pString" select="substring-after($pString,';')"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pPosition" select="$pPosition + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

XML file

```
<RECORD_SET>
    <RECORD NUM="1">
        <Title>Title1</Title>
        <Author>Author Name 1; Author Location 1; Author Phone Number 1</Author>
        <Date>11/20/1976</Date>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD NUM="2">
        <Title>Title2</Title>
        <Author>Author Name 2; Author Location 2; Author Phone Number 2
        Author Name 3; Author Location 3; Author Phone Number 3
        Author Name 4; Author Location 4; Author Phone Number 4</Author>
        <Date>10/20/2001</Date>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD NUM="3">
        <Title>Title3</Title>
        <Author>Author Name 5; Author Location 5; Author Phone Number 5
        Author Name 6; Author Location 6; Author Phone Number 6</Author>
        <Date>09/18/1966</Date>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD NUM="4">
        <Title>Title4</Title>
        <Author>Author Name 7
        Author Name 8</Author>
        <Date>01/18/1956</Date>
    </RECORD>
</RECORD_SET>
```

Desired output

```
<RECORD_SET>
    <RECORD NUM="1">
        <Title>Title1</Title>
        <AuthorName>Author Name 1</Author>
        <AuthorLocation>Author Location 1</AuthorLocation>
        <AuthorPhone>Author Phone Number 1</AuthorPhone>
        <Date>11/20/1976</Date>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD NUM="2">
        <Title>Title2</Title>
        <AuthorName>Author Name 2</Author>
        <AuthorLocation>Author Location 2</AuthorLocation>
        <AuthorPhone>Author Phone Number 2</AuthorPhone>
        <AuthorName>Author Name 3</Author>
        <AuthorLocation>Author Location 3</AuthorLocation>
        <AuthorPhone>Author Phone Number 3</AuthorPhone>
        <AuthorName>Author Name 4</Author>
        <AuthorLocation>Author Location 4</AuthorLocation>
        <AuthorPhone>Author Phone Number 4</AuthorPhone>
        <Date>10/20/2001</Date>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD NUM="3">
        <Title>Title3</Title>
        <AuthorName>Author Name 5</Author>
        <AuthorLocation>Author Location 5</AuthorLocation>
        <AuthorPhone>Author Phone Number 5</AuthorPhone>
        <AuthorName>Author Name 6</Author>
        <AuthorLocation>Author Location 6</AuthorLocation>
        <AuthorPhone>Author Phone Number 6</AuthorPhone>
        <Date>09/18/1966</Date>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD NUM="4">
        <Title>Title4</Title>
        <AuthorName>Author Name 7</AuthorName>
        <AuthorName>Author Name 8</AuthorName>
        <Date>01/18/1956</Date>
    </RECORD>
</RECORD_SET>
```

Current Output

```
<RECORD NUM="1">
    <Title>Title1</Title>
    <Author>
      <AuthorName>Author Name 1</AuthorName>
      <AuthorLocation>Author Location 1</AuthorLocation>
      <AuthorPhone>Author Phone Number 1</AuthorPhone>
    </Author>
    <Date>11/20/1976</Date>
</RECORD>
<RECORD NUM="2">
    <Title>Title2</Title>
    <Author>
      <AuthorName>Author Name 2</AuthorName>
      <AuthorLocation>Author Location 2</AuthorLocation>
      <AuthorPhone>Author Phone Number 2 Author Name 3</AuthorPhone>Author Location 3Author Phone Number 3 Author Name 4Author Location 4Author Phone Number 4
    </Author>
    <Date>10/20/2001</Date>
</RECORD>
<RECORD NUM="3">
    <Title>Title3</Title>
    <Author>
      <AuthorName>Author Name 5</AuthorName>
      <AuthorLocation>Author Location 5</AuthorLocation>
      <AuthorPhone>Author Phone Number 5 Author Name 6</AuthorPhone>Author Location 6Author Phone Number 6
    </Author>
    <Date>09/18/1966</Date>
</RECORD>
<RECORD NUM="4">
    <Title>Title4</Title>
    <Author>
      <AuthorName>Author Name 7 Author Name 8</AuthorName>
    </Author>
    <Date>01/18/1956</Date>
</RECORD>
```

Comment: What's the output coming of as-of-now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vAuthorDataNames" select=
  "'AuthorName', 'AuthorLocation', 'AuthorPhone'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Author">
  <xsl:variable name="vAuthors" select="tokenize(., '(\n(\r?))\s*')"/>

  <xsl:for-each select="$vAuthors[normalize-space(.)]">
   <xsl:variable name="vAuthorData" select="tokenize(., ';\s*')"/>

   <xsl:for-each select="$vAuthorData">
    <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>

    <xsl:element name="{$vAuthorDataNames[$vPos]}">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<RECORD_SET>
    <RECORD NUM="1">
        <Title>Title1</Title>
        <Author>Author Name 1; Author Location 1; Author Phone Number 1</Author>
        <Date>11/20/1976</Date>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD NUM="2">
        <Title>Title2</Title>
        <Author>Author Name 2; Author Location 2; Author Phone Number 2
        Author Name 3; Author Location 3; Author Phone Number 3
        Author Name 4; Author Location 4; Author Phone Number 4</Author>
        <Date>10/20/2001</Date>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD NUM="3">
        <Title>Title3</Title>
        <Author>Author Name 5; Author Location 5; Author Phone Number 5
        Author Name 6; Author Location 6; Author Phone Number 6</Author>
        <Date>09/18/1966</Date>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD NUM="4">
        <Title>Title4</Title>
        <Author>Author Name 7
        Author Name 8</Author>
        <Date>01/18/1956</Date>
    </RECORD>
</RECORD_SET>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<RECORD_SET>
   <RECORD NUM="1">
      <Title>Title1</Title>
      <AuthorName>Author Name 1</AuthorName>
      <AuthorLocation>Author Location 1</AuthorLocation>
      <AuthorPhone>Author Phone Number 1</AuthorPhone>
      <Date>11/20/1976</Date>
   </RECORD>
   <RECORD NUM="2">
      <Title>Title2</Title>
      <AuthorName>Author Name 2</AuthorName>
      <AuthorLocation>Author Location 2</AuthorLocation>
      <AuthorPhone>Author Phone Number 2</AuthorPhone>
      <AuthorName>Author Name 3</AuthorName>
      <AuthorLocation>Author Location 3</AuthorLocation>
      <AuthorPhone>Author Phone Number 3</AuthorPhone>
      <AuthorName>Author Name 4</AuthorName>
      <AuthorLocation>Author Location 4</AuthorLocation>
      <AuthorPhone>Author Phone Number 4</AuthorPhone>
      <Date>10/20/2001</Date>
   </RECORD>
   <RECORD NUM="3">
      <Title>Title3</Title>
      <AuthorName>Author Name 5</AuthorName>
      <AuthorLocation>Author Location 5</AuthorLocation>
      <AuthorPhone>Author Phone Number 5</AuthorPhone>
      <AuthorName>Author Name 6</AuthorName>
      <AuthorLocation>Author Location 6</AuthorLocation>
      <AuthorPhone>Author Phone Number 6</AuthorPhone>
      <Date>09/18/1966</Date>
   </RECORD>
   <RECORD NUM="4">
      <Title>Title4</Title>
      <AuthorName>Author Name 7</AuthorName>
      <AuthorName>Author Name 8</AuthorName>
      <Date>01/18/1956</Date>
   </RECORD>
</RECORD_SET>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the satndard XSLT functions **[`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)** and **[`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space)**.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre.  My apologies for not specifying it in my original question, but I'm using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @HammerTime, With XSLT 1.0 one can mechanically translate this XSLT 2.0 solution to XSLT 1.0. Or use FXSL's str-split-words` template. Or write their own recursive solution -- this would be 5 times bigger and difficult to maintain. Switch to XSLT 2.0...